# Windows phone 8.1 background tasks

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I just downloaded the universal app background task sample application for windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9

So after going through the code, I understand that the background task is being implemented using the windows runtime component. I am trying to use the timertrigger.

Is it a possibility that the background task be implemented using the Silverlight 8.1 windows phone project instead of a windows runtime project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer above is wrong. Wonder how it has 5 votes. Anyways, background task cannot run in a silverlight applciation but it can only register a background task. It has to be a runtime project that runs a background task.

A silverlight application can just register a background task which is a separate runtime project. Its a different process all together.

Comment: No your answer is wrong. Background Tasks project (Windows RunTime Component) works in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 too.

Comment: What do u mean by works in silverlight project too ?

Comment: Means you can reference a WRC bg task project in a WP Silverlight 8.1 project and it will work too.

Comment: You can refer a WRT project from Silverlight project. The question here was diff. Please read the question first completely.

Comment: "Anyways, background task cannot run in a silverlight applciation. It has to be a runtime project." Isn't this a bit misleading?

Comment: @xin. made it better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The reason why they chose a Windows Runtime project in this example was to show the new Universal Apps. You can use the BackGroundTasks in a Silverlight based project and in a Windows Runtime base project.

But if you ever plan to expand you app to Windows 8 you should think about making it a Universal App.

Comment: Sorry. This does not work. Background Task has to be a runtime component.